# Getting hidden password in a 64 bit Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I wish to password protect a batch I found a way that works but get an error on 64 bit machines my code is:

```
echo off
echo hP1X500P[PZBBBfh#b##fXf-V@`$fPf]f3/f1/5++u5>hide.com

:retry
set /p userid=Enter UserId:
echo Technician Name: %userid% >> case.txt
set /p password=Enter password: <nul
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('hide.com') do set password=%%i
if /i %password%==password goto next
cls
echo Try again. You are not logged in!
goto retry

:next
echo. & echo You are logged in!

pause
del hide.com
```

the error I get is this:

> Unsupported 16-Bit Application
>   The program or feature "\??\C:\Users\Jamie\Desktop\hide.com" cannot start or run due to incompatibity with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available.

please help

Comment: Who wrote the encrypter?  There are others available - for example: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/scriptcompilers.php - while not batch scripting, AutoIT / AutoHotKey work too - http://alternativeto.net/software/winbatch/

Answer (score 1):

Test this:  then change echo lines that are not indented

```
::!CARLOS_HIDE_INPUT.BAT
::Code by Carlos on AMBNT 2013-03-10
::Subject: Getkey without Display the input.
::Thread started by jeb

   :::::::::::::BEGIN OF CODE:::::::::::::   
   @Echo Off   
   :HInput
   ::Version 3.0     
   SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Echo Enter your password below:
   Set "Line="
   Rem Save 0x08 character in BS variable
   For /F %%# In (
   '"Prompt;$H&For %%# in (1) Do Rem"'
   ) Do Set "BS=%%#"

   :HILoop
   Set "Key="
   For /F "delims=" %%# In (
   'Xcopy /L /W "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>Nul'
   ) Do If Not Defined Key Set "Key=%%#"
   Set "Key=%Key:~-1%"
   SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   If Not Defined Key Goto :HIEnd
   If %BS%==^%Key% (Set /P "=%BS% %BS%" <Nul
   Set "Key="
   If Defined Line Set "Line=!Line:~0,-1!"
   ) Else Set /P "=*" <Nul
   If Not Defined Line (EndLocal &Set "Line=%Key%"
   ) Else For /F delims^=^ eol^= %%# In (
   "!Line!") Do EndLocal &Set "Line=%%#%Key%"
   Goto :HILoop

   :HIEnd
   Echo(
Echo Your password is '!Line!'
   Pause
   Goto :Eof

   ::::::::::::::END OF CODE::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an open-source tool called **editenv** that can do this:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/editenv

It provides the `--maskinput` (`-m`) option[*] that lets you hide the typed input. Example:

```
editenv --maskinput --prompt="Password: " PWD
```

This command displays a Password: prompt, and whatever you enter is placed in the PWD environment variable.

Download here:

https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/editenv/releases

[*] Note that the `--maskinput` (`-m`) option is not secure -- typed input is placed in plain-text in the environment. This feature is for convenience only.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
echo off

REM Find out if we're running as 64-bit
IF NOT "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%"=="x86" (
ECHO.Relaunching the script in a 32-bit process...
%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWow64\cmd.exe /c "%0"
GOTO :EOF
)

echo hP1X500P[PZBBBfh#b##fXf-V@`$fPf]f3/f1/5++u5>hide.com

:retry
set /p userid=Enter UserId:
echo Technician Name: %userid% >> case.txt
set /p password=Enter password: <nul
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('hide.com') do set password=%%i
if /i %password%==password goto next
cls
echo Try again. You are not logged in!
goto retry

:next
echo. & echo You are logged in!

pause
del hide.com
```

I added a little bit of functionality that detects the current architecture and relaunches the BAT in a 32-bit process if it's not currently in a 32-bit process.

Comment: 64-bit Windows cannot run an MS-DOS executable (16 bit), so this solution simply doesn't work at all on a 64-bit platform, even if you launch as 32-bit.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Good catch.  I'm sure I read the "16-bit" note, but in my head was thinking 64 vs 32.